# Capturing Block passed into method when using OCMock

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, ocmock

I'm looking to capture a block that is passed into a mock object. Here is the concrete function of class being mocked:

```
[self.imageFetcher fetchImageWithURL:url success:^(NSURL *successUrl, UIImage *image) {
       //Implementation Details here
}];
```

Here is the my attempt to capturing the block:

```
OCMExpect([imageFetcher fetchImageWithURL:urlForSuccess success:[OCMArg checkWithBlock:^(void(^myBlock)(NSURL *,UIImage *)){
        myBlock(urlForSuccess,[UIImage new]);
        return YES;
    }]]);
```

However, this doesn't seem to be working. How can I use the `checkWithBlock` to capture the block and be able to call that block with parameters I choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to invoke the block that is passed to the mock, then you should use `[OCMArg invokeBlock]`. See section 2.6 in the documentation for details: http://ocmock.org/reference/#stubing-methods